# sed get specific pattern and change it

Tags: sed

I have file with following content

```
<general id="7" src="xyz" srcType="abc" link="positive" />
<general id="3" src="xyz" srcType="pqr" link="positive" />
..
```

I am trying to replace every `src` name with its capitalize word. For example in above I want to replace all `xyz` with `Xyz` (first letter is capital).

Expected output is

```
<general id="7" src="Xyz" srcType="abc" link="positive" />
<general id="3" src="Xyz" srcType="pqr" link="positive" />
..
```

I [tried](https://regex101.com/r/qLBSpR/1) regex pattern `src="(.*?)"` which can extract 'xyz' from the line but how can I use it with `sed` to replace in my file?

I tried following but it is not working

> sed -E 's/srcName="(.*?)"/Xyz/1' filename

Bonus question, how can I generalize it? Where anything between `scr="` and `"` can be converted into word capitalizing first character.

Answer (score 3):

To edit XML, use an XML-aware tool. For example, there's [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), a tool I adopted to maintain.

```
open file.xml ;
for //@src set . xsh:subst(., "(.)", "\U$1") ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A XML-aware tool, is definitely the way! For a quick hack:

in GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/src="([a-z])/src="\U\1\E/g'  file.xml
```

for more complex changes I suggest Perl

```
perl -pe 's/src="\K(\w+)/ucfirst($1)/e'   file.xml
```

where

- `perl -pe command` is a "readline, command, print" loop
- `s/regexp/expression/e`  substitutes regexp by the result of eval(expression)
- `src="\K`   is a left-context pattern

Comment: I think you can drop the `+` from `\w+` and just use `s/src="\K(\w)/uc $1/e` since it's only the first letter after the quote character we're interested in.

Comment: Also, use `\u` in perl, there's no need to eval.

Comment: @ilkkachu, you are right. I was planning something more complex `ucfirst(lc($1))`

Comment: @choroba, you are right, That is equal to the sed version. In order to show the more powerful `s///e` I was planning `perl -pe 's/src="\K(\w+)/ucfirst(lc($1))/e' `, but that can still be done with `\u` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with awk command and it worked fine

```
awk -F 'src="' '{$2=(toupper(substr($2,1,1))substr($2,2));$2="src="$2;print $0}' filename|sed 's/src=/&"/g'
```

output

```
<general id="7"  src="Xyz" srcType="abc" link="positive" />
<general id="3"  src="Xyz" srcType="pqr" link="positive" />
```